# How to remove scroll indicator in a block of code [Stack Overflow in Chrome, Mac]?

Tags: support, bug

Lately I've been getting annoyed at the horizontal scroll indicator whenever there's a block of code on Stack Overflow. I think it's a bug, isn't it?

If not, is there a way to remove this or cancel scrolling? This happens especially if the block of code is a couple of lines. The only way I know to reproduce this to visit a question and just right after or before the page completes loading, scroll the block of code horizontally and hover the mouse pointer outside such block.

**Screenshot #1**

[image]

**Screenshot #2**

[image]

**End of screenshots**

Comment: Thanks for marking this as a duplicate. Saw the similar question and the answer to it.